# Android check what side of the screen the Navigation Bar is on

Tags: android

I am trying to support 4.4 translucent navigation bars. I ended up using the code below to move an item that was hidden under the navigation bar if the device version is 4.4.

```
    int resID = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resID));
```

That worked fine but then I noticed it was applying this in landscape too. I checked the current display rotation and only apply the padding if it is in portrait. That worked on phones but on tablets the navigation bar is present on the bottom in landscape too.

I am wondering is there a way to identify what side of the screen the Navigation Bar is on?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use `Gravity.LEFT` or `Gravity.Right`